# How to update page in django without page refresh?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

So.I have prices in database django,when I change it,prices on website dont change and I have to restart django server.So..How Can I refresh  page in django without restart django server?

Comment: you don't need to restart the server. if your website is calling api on reloding page, that should be enough.

Comment: Eh...No.It isnot working. I need to reload page when I change prices.

Comment: Django itself can't refresh a page without reloading it. You probably need help from JavaScript techniques like AJAX.

Comment: I neet to connect ajax in all page where I want to change prices?